# HTML Form IF statements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to HTML and javascript and I have a problem with a code sample. Basically the code is intended to use with checkboxes but I want it to be used with a certain dropdownmenu aka select option.

```
<input id="more" type="checkbox">Add More Users</input>
<div id="yourDiv"> ...other form... </div>

<script>
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('more').onclick = function () {
        if (this.checked)
            document.getElementById('yourDiv').style.display = 'block';
        else
            document.getElementById('yourDiv').style.display = 'none';  
    }
}
</script>
```

What I want it to do is check the menubar onchange and show a new menubar depending on what selection the user picks. So for example option 1 would open menubar1 and so on.

So far I worked out the code below, I do not know if it's even close to a solution though.

**So this code below is what triggers the script**

```
<select id="Ärende" name="Ärende" required onchange=FuncÄrende()>
          <option id="BeställningY" value="Beställning">Beställning</option>
          <option id="AnmälanY" value="Anmälan">Anmälan</option>
          <option id="BehörighetY" value="Behörighet">Behörighet</option>
          <option id="MiljörondY" value="Miljörond">Miljörond</option>
          <option id="AnnatY" value="Annat">Annat</option>
        </select>
```

**This code below is the script which will "unlock/show" the different divs I have all the other menubars in. This code is for the BeställningDiv. The rest of them looks the same with some differences ofc, so I only include one of em.**

```
    <script>
            function FuncÄrende() {
              var Ärende = document.getElementById("Ärende");
              var ÄrendeValue = Ärende.options[Ärende.selectedIndex].value;

              if      (document.getElementById('BeställningY').value == "Beställning") {
                document.getElementById("BeställningDiv").style.display == "block";
                document.getElementById("AnmälanDiv").style.display == "none";
                document.getElementById("BehörighetDiv").style.display == "none";
                document.getElementById("MiljörondDiv").style.display == "none";
                document.getElementById("AnnatDiv").style.display == "none";
}
        }
      </script>
```

**And finally this code below is one example of the different divs that the script will unlock.**

```
<div id="BeställningDiv" style="display:none;">
    <h4 id="BeställningT">Beställning</h4>
        <select id="Beställning" name="Beställning">
          <option value="IT-Utrustning">IT-Utrustning</option>
          <option value="Kontors materiell">Kontors materiell</option>
          <option value="Belysning">Belysning</option>
          <option value="Ergonomi">Ergonomi</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

And please supply me with easy to understand solutions as I'm very new to HTML. I spent about 9 hours in my whole life with HTML and this is how far Ive come. Thanks in advance - Kind regards,
Oliver

Comment: I think you skip `{}`

Comment: Can you add full example.

Comment: Where is `document.getElementById("srt")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you tackle your problem from a different, it is actually not too complicated: you simply want to toggle the appearance of other elements based on the value of the select element.

- Therefore, the **ground** state of other elements should be hidden, and you always reset to ground state when the select option is updated.
- Now that is established, you need to know that JS is not reactive: in order to listen to changes to the `<select>` elements value, you will have to bind event listeners to your `Arende` select. This can be done by using `.addEventListener()` method.
- Use `switch` statements instead of deeply nested if/else statements. Imagine if you have 25 different options, that means your if/else tree will be nested 25 levels deep!

Here is an example code that you can work with. It is definitely **far from optimal**, because there are several things that you can change to improve performance (see notes at the end):

```
var Arende = document.getElementById("Arende");
var Rubrik2 = document.getElementById("srt");
var Bestallning = document.getElementById("Bestallning");
var Anmalan = document.getElementById("Anmalan");

// Listen to changes in <select>
Arende.addEventListener('change', function() {

  // Get the value of selected <option>
  var value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

  // Hide all other elements
  // I recomemnd that you give these elements a class instead!
  Rubrik2.style.display = 'none';
  Bestallning.style.display = 'none';
  Anmalan.style.display = 'none';

  // Now we use switch statements to go through all the options
  switch(value) {

    case 'Bestallning':
      Bestallning.style.display = 'block';
      break;

    case 'Anmalan':
      Anmalan.style.display = 'block';
      break;

    // And etc...

  }

});
```

### Notes for code optimization and improvement

1. You should assign a class to all the "other elements" whose appearance are dependent on the value of your `<select>` element. This makes it very easy to apply a blanket `style.display = 'none'` statement to all of them, instead of having to enumerate through all your elements manually
2. Attach `<option>` to target element mapping information in the `<option>` itself, such as via HTML5 `data-` attribute. This makes it a lot easier and we do not even need to use `switch/case` statements at all. In the example below I have assumed that the value of the `<option>` directly corresponds to the ID of the element you want to show.

Here is a more proof-of-concept code:

```js
var Arende = document.getElementById("Arende");
var Bestallning = document.getElementById("Bestallning");
var Anmalan = document.getElementById("Anmalan");

// Listen to changes in <select>
Arende.addEventListener('change', function() {

  // Get the value of selected <option>
  var value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

  // Hide all other elements, but show the one whose ID matches option value
  var otherElements = document.querySelectorAll('.otherElements');
  for (var i = 0; i < otherElements.length; i++) {
    var el = otherElements[i];
    
    if (el.id === value)
      el.style.display = 'block';
    else
      el.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h4>Arende</h4>
<select id="Arende" name="Arende" required>
    <option value="Bestallning">Bestallning</option>
    <option value="Anmalan">Anmalan</option>
</select>

<!-- Other elements -->
<div id="Bestallning" class="otherElements hidden">Bestallning</div>
<div id="Anmalan" class="otherElements hidden">Anmalan</div>
```

Comment: It should have `.value` to get value from id

Comment: @JigarShah I am getting the value, what do you mean?

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick and good answer, it is unfortunately alittle too complex for me to understand at this point. Could you take a look at my edit on the main post? @Terry

Comment: @OliverPersson Next time, update your question with the correct markup so that nobody wastes time on an example that is not relevant to your use case.

Comment: My first question was relevant back then, as that was what I was trying to figure out. All those helpful but also very complicated answers launched me on an adventure to seek other ways and I found the one I edited now, but I need help to modify it. Sorry for any inconvenience with the duplicated post and stuff. @Terry

Answer (score 0):

```
    function run() {
var Arende = document.getElementById("Arende");
var Rubrik2 = document.getElementById("srt");
var Bestallning = document.getElementById("Bestallning");
var Anmalan = document.getElementById("Anmalan");
if (Arende == "Bestallning") {
  Rubrik2.text == "Behorighet";
  Bestallning.style.display = "block";
}
  else if
    (Arende == "Anmalan") {
      Rubrik2.text == "Anmalan";
      Anmalan.style.display = "block";
 }
      else{
        rubrik2.style.display = "none";
        Anmalan.style.display = "none";
        Bestallning.style.display = "none";

    }

}
```

You forgot the `{}` after the last else, also next to the function `run()` you need to open `{` and add all the code inside of it then close it `}`

Comment: Wrong: you also missed closing brace for `if`

Answer (score 0):

```
var Arende = document.getElementById("Arende");
var ArendeValue = Arende.options[Arende.selectedIndex].value;
```

This is the correct way of getting the value. What you are doing will get you the element which is useful for the answer I provided.

Also, I would suggest you to learn the Chrome DevTools, it is perfect to debug things quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of braces mistakes please compare with below code:

```
function run() { // braces for function
  var Arende = document.getElementById("Arende").value; // notice .value
  var Rubrik2 = document.getElementById("srt").value;
  var Bestallning = document.getElementById("Bestallning").value;
  var Anmalan = document.getElementById("Anmalan").value;
  if (Arende == "Bestallning") {
    Rubrik2.text = "Behorighet"; // single =
    Bestallning.style.display = "block";
  } // need to be closed here and same for other
  else if (Arende == "Anmalan") {
    Rubrik2.text = "Anmalan"; // single =
    Anmalan.style.display = "block";
  }
  else {
    rubrik2.style.display = "none";
    Anmalan.style.display = "none";
    Bestallning.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all of the helpful tips, I will look into those and come back later and tell you how it worked out. Also if I may ask, I succeeded in making the form UTF-8, but the "mailto" still uses the default charset and therefor all the options and answers looks weird in the mail, is there anyway I could fix this? This is the code I currently have there

<form action="mailto:mymail@mymail.com" accept-charset="UFT-8" method="post" enctype="text/plain">

Comment: I have updated my answer for `Rubrik2.text == "Behorighet";` to `Rubrik2.text = "Behorighet";` please replace with current code

Answer (score 0):

It is just that you have syntax errors and unfortunately it is just about {}
Add them after the `else` and close it at the end. Also add it after `function run()` and close it at the end as rightly mentioned by Peter.

Else you are doing good as a beginner but make sure never to mess-up the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Below you'll find a sample solution.

Take a close look to how I'm using class names as part of my solution.

Basically, when option changes, grab the value, which is the class name of the menu I want to show. Hide and show using css.

Let me know if anything isn't clear

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".options").on("change", function() {
    let val = $(this).val();
    $(".menu").removeClass("menu--active");
    $(`.${val}`).addClass("menu--active");
  });
});
```

```css
.menus {
}

.menu {
  display: none;
}

.menu--active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="options">
  <option value="menu--first">Pick first Menu</option>
  <option value="menu--second">Pick second Menu</option>
</select>

<div class="menus">
  <div class="menus__menu menu menu--first menu--active">This contains the first menu</div>
  <div class="menus__menu menu menu--second">This contains the second menu</div>

</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work when I place it in "run code snippet" and that's great. However it seems overly complicated. Like seriously is HTML so unoptimised? Lets compare it to other languages where it is 2 lines of code to both check the change and show/hide another div. The thing is that I need this code on about 14 different places in my complete code. So in other words, isn't there an easier way? I'm sorry if I sound rude, I'm really thankful to the help you supply but I'm doing this code to learn and I feel I'm way over my head right now. It seemed like and easy thing at first. @zsawaf

Comment: @OliverPersson I think you're thinking in the box too much with your solution. Sometimes you can't literally tell javascript what to do line by line, but you have to find more general solutions. There are probably more optimal solutions than mine, but it's the first thing that came to my mind. But do you understand what's happening with the code? If you do, it's so easy and elegant.

Comment: I must admit that no I don't really understand what's going on. I understand the basic underline but I do not understand for example how the script knows what selection it should look at. If I could only recreate this script one time on my own project I may be able to recreate it over and over for every time I need it. And yes I do have to admit as a C# coder myself that the code itself is pretty neat. It's just that I don't understand it yet :P Could you help me recreate it on the "problem/sample" I posted on the main page?

Comment: Do you see the line let val = $(this).val()? Immediately after, console log val, and look at what val is when you switch between options. At the same time look at the class names of the two menus. You should find a relationship between the two. If you're having a hard time with it, I suggest you do a bit more basic tutorials, then try tackling this when you feel more comfortable :) Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, the final solution I decided to use was the following

```
<script>
        $("#Kablarsladdarladdare").change(function(){
          if($(this).val() == "Sladd"){
            $("#SladdDetaljDiv").show();
            $("#SladdDetalj").prop("disabled", false);
          }else{
            $("#SladdDetaljDiv").hide();
            $("#SladdDetalj").prop("disabled", true);
          }
        });
      </script>
```

This is repeating on each "select" to determine which new selection should be visible.